# CodeChef runtime error(sigsegv)

Tags: c, arrays

**CodeChef Problem:**

Shivam is the youngest programmer in the world, he is just 12 years old. Shivam is learning programming and today he is writing his first program.

Program is very simple, Given two integers A and B, write a program to add these two numbers.

Input
The first line contains an integer T, total number of test cases. Then follow T lines, each line contains two Integers A and B.

Output
Add A and B and display it.

Constraints
1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1 ≤ A,B ≤ 10000
Example
Input
3 
1 2
100 200
10 40

Output
3
300
50

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int T, A, B, i, sum[T];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A);
            scanf("%d",&B);
            sum[i]=A+B;
        }

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", sum[i]);
    }

}
```

**Error**
Runtime Error SIGSEGV - I searched it, it says array out of bounds.

Comment: And what is the value of `T` when you declare `sum[T]`?

Comment: I'm taking `T` as user input.

Comment: Then declare sum after reading T

Comment: Okay. but the code works fine on my machine but gives an error on codechef

Comment: Yeah - it's UB.  You use a local var before initializing/loading it.  'code works fine on my machine' no, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

`T` has an indeterminate value when you declare `sum[T]`. Instead, do:

```
int main()
{
    int T, A, B, i;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    int sum[T];
    for(i=0;i<T;i++) ...
```

Ans you should check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate the memory runtime (during the programs execution) it would be more appropriate to use a function such as "malloc". Here is a short example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int T, A, B, i;
    int *sum;

    scanf("%d", &T);
    if (T <= 0) /*Check if the value of T is appropriate*/
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument T!\n");
    }

    /* Dynamically allocate the memory */
    sum = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*T);
    if (sum == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory!\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
            scanf("%d",&A);
            scanf("%d",&B);
            sum[i]=A+B;
        }

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", sum[i]);
    }

    /* Free the allocated memory once you are not needing it anymore in 
    order to avoid memory leaks */
    free(sum);

    return (0);
}
```

Note: This is just an example how to avoid the runtime error I have not taken a close look at the rest of the logic related with the for loops.

Comment: I prefer the dynamic allocation too, just don't forget to **free** the pointer

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and the feedback @Hollyol !

Answer (score 0):

Declare sum[T] after taking the input value of T